# Expose On Prem Git Server to Internet

Tags: git, saas, ibm-jazz

We use Rational Team Concert (SaaS) as ALM tool and we would like to use an on premises Git server for source control (https://git-scm.com). How can I access my on premises git server from a cloud software? Is there a way to configure a public url to it?

Comment: And which git server software would that be? And how did you set it up? If you've set up a git server on your corporate network, it should just be about exposing that server to the internet. Your IT department should help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

Rational Team Concert can be integrated with:

- [GitHub Enterprise](https://enterprise.github.com/home)
- [GitLab](https://gitlab.com)
- [Gerrit](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/)
- Other Git server with server-side hooks

For details on how to integrate Rational Team Concert with theses products read [Integrating Rational Team Concert and Git](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYMRC_6.0.6/com.ibm.team.connector.cq.doc/topics/c_integ_git.html) and follow the specific task.

Comment: I can infer by your answer that I can only integrate with cloud git services and not with on (my) premises git server. Is that correct?

Comment: No, each of the product mentioned in my answer can be installed on-premises and integrated to Rational Team Concert.

Answer (score 0):

IBM offers two IBM RTC hostings, one is managed service and the second one is pure SaaS.

For the first one you can request VPN tunnel between your data center and managed IBM Rational Team Concert and IBM should provide that.

**If you have true IBM RTC SaaS which is multitenant, you need to expose Git that both servers will see each other and there is no workaround for that.**